# Verticial UIStackView center align two UILabels inside

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

There is a Root UIStackView with an ImageView and Information UIStackView with two UILabels. I'm attempting to center the two labels in the UIStackView. I have tried adding a center constraint to the stack view to the center of the image. The top label grows and doesn't hug it's content.

```
private let stack: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    stackView.spacing = 8
    return stackView
}()
private let informationStack: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    return stackView
}()
```

Current Output:
[image]

Desired Output:
[image]

Comment: The alignment on your horizontal stack view should be `stackView.alignment = .center`

Comment: Can you provide a complete code example, perhaps a playground, that shows all the views and the unexpected results you are seeing?  Your image shows the expected result, but not what the failed case is yielding and your code example does not include the image to labels.

Comment: @ScottThompson yes, in the future I will add playground. Thanks for the suggestion. This is my first swift question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

    import UIKit
    import PlaygroundSupport

    let stack: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing = 8
        return stackView
    }()

    let informationStack: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        return stackView
    }()

    let timeLabel = UILabel()
    timeLabel.text = "9:30 AM"
    timeLabel.textColor = .white
    informationStack.addArrangedSubview(timeLabel)

    let eventLabel = UILabel()
    eventLabel.textColor = .white
    eventLabel.font = eventLabel.font.withSize(24)
    eventLabel.text = "Faith, Hope & Love"
    informationStack.addArrangedSubview(eventLabel)

    let drizzle = UIImage(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill")
    let drizzleView = UIImageView(image: drizzle)
    drizzleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
    drizzleView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    drizzleView.backgroundColor = .white
    drizzleView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    drizzleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 175).isActive = true
    drizzleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    stack.addArrangedSubview(drizzleView)
    stack.addArrangedSubview(informationStack)
    debugPrint(stack.arrangedSubviews)

    stack.bounds = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 512,height: 125)
    stack.backgroundColor = .black

    PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = stack
```

Comment: Scott, thank you for going above and beyond with a whole playground code up. I was struggling with this for awhile. Seeing the adjustment is .center alignment on the horizontal stack I can't believe I didn't see that. I appreciate the effort and help.

Comment: I should note that DonMag made the suggestion in comments on the original question long before I had a chance to play with the code.  Kudos to DonMag!